# Create an Instance of class which does DI via Playframework Guice Independently in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I'm working on Playframework2.5 with play-slick and programs related to it such as batch.

current project structure is like

```
/rootPlayProject
  /app
    /controllers
    /filters
    /services
    ...
  Modules
  /core (sub-project - DAOs,services are placed here)
  /batch (sub-project depends on core)
```

I'm using Guice DI almost everywhere include Database Access Object(DAO).
And interfaces in core are bound in `Module` placed in `core` which end up getting inherited by `Module` in root project.

Core Module(/rootPlayProject/core/CoreModule.scala)

```
class CoreModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[FooDAO]).to(classOf[FooDAOImpl])
    ....
  }
}
```

Root Module(/rootPlayProject/Modules.scala)

```
class Module extends CoreModule {
  override def configure() = {
    super.configure()
    bind(classOf[FooService]).to(classOf[FooServiceImpl])
  }
}
```

This works pretty well as Playframework application though, I would like to use core module for batch programs and I would like to run the batches without playframework.

so far I tried something like this

```
object BatchA {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val injector = Guice.createInjector(new CoreModule)
    val foo = injector.getInstance(classOf[FooDAO])
    //do something with foo.
  }
}
```

but since my DAO's requiring things Playframework create such as `ExecutionContext`,`play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider` and `@play.db.NamedDatabase`, above code does not run.

My question is, How can I let those things get bound without play application builder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GuiceInjectorBuilder` do the trick.

```
trait PlayInjector {
  lazy val injector = new GuiceInjectorBuilder().configure(Configuration.load(Environment.simple(mode = Mode.Dev)))
  .bindings(new BuiltinModule, new CoreModule, new SlickModule).disable(classOf[Application]).injector

  def closeInjector = injector.instanceOf[DefaultApplicationLifecycle].stop
}
```

BuiltinModule binds Play basic modules such as `ExecutionContext`, `ExecutionContextExecutor` or `ActorSystem`.
You can make your own Module to bind only things you need to though, using `BuiltinModule` and disable classes you don't need is simpler.

how to use it

```
object Foo extends PlayInjector {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val foo = injector.instanceOf[FooDAO]
    val bar = injector.instanceOf[BarDAO]
    //do something
    //when you finish things you want to do
    closeInjector
  }
}
```

Since some modules like PlaySlick uses `ApplicationLifecycle.addStopHook` to handle closing operation. It's safer to execute them instead of just call `sys.exit()`

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether or not you want to actually decouple Play Framework from your DAOs.

**Option 1: Don't Decouple**

Your main method could simply have the following lines preceeding your `val injector` line:

```
val application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  .in(Environment(new File("."), this.getClass.getClassLoader, Mode.Prod))
  .build
Play.start(application)
```

**Option 2: Decouple**

Or, you can provide injectable classes that can provide the `ExecutionContext`  specific to the environment. If you want to inject the `DatabaseConfigProvider`, you will have to perform further abstractions to remove the direct dependency on Play. The annotation will follow the Play-specific implementation of the abstraction.

---

In the case of my own project where I encountered this scenario, I opted for Option 1, as the dependency on Play wasn't severe enough of an impact for me.

Comment: the case of `Option1` it means play application is running while I do what I want right? If it's not too hard to do, I prefer the latter one so I don't have to run play application to exec just a batch.

Comment: In your case, Option 2 might be more reasonable.