# How to get application.conf variable in an object using Scala and Play 2.5.x?

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, guice

I used to get the `application.conf` variable in Play 2.4.x with `Play.current.configuration.getString('NAME_HERE')`, and it was working good in class, object and companion object too.

Now, I'm using Play 2.5.4 with Scala in a new project, and I won't use this `Play.current`, because it's deprecated, but there is an alternative using DI, like this :

```
class HomeController @Inject() (configuration: play.api.Configuration) extends Controller {
  def config = Action {
    Ok(configuration.underlying.getString("db.driver"))
  }
}
```

This DI Injection works like a charm in class, but in this project, I need to get the variable `db.driver` in a object? And as far I know, with an object I can't use DI.

Maybe using Guice would help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Singleton` annotated class instead of `object`

```
trait Foo {}

@Singleton
class FooImpl @Inject()(configuration: play.api.Configuration)) extends Foo {
  //do whatever you want
}
```

`@Singleton` makes the class singleton.It feels bit awkward because Scala itself natively have syntax `object` to create a singleton, But this is the easiest and probably best solution to DI into a singleton.

You also may create the singleton eagerly like the code below.

`bind(classOf[Foo]).to(classOf[FooImpl])asEagerSingleton()`

for more detail Info, You can look up [Google Guice Wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#eager-singletons) and [Playframework site](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection)

**EDIT**

How you call it is exactly the same as how you DI in Playframework2.5.

```
class BarController @Inject()(foo: Foo) extends Controller {
  //Do whatever you want with Foo
}
```

Guice basically generates new instance every time you DI, Once you put `@Singleton`, Guice use only one instance instead.

DI is for anti-high coupling.So when you want to use a class you defined from another class,You need to DI otherwise the classes are highly coupled which end up making it harder to code your unit test.

FYI, You can use them outside of Play with this technique.

[Create an Instance of class which does DI via Playframework Guice Independently in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471551/create-an-instance-of-class-which-does-di-via-playframework-guice-independently)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
val myConfig = ConfigFactory.load().getString("myConfig.key")
```

Above approach doesn't require you to convert your object to singleton class.

Comment: Thanks, @nir! Do you know why does `ConfigFactory.load()` work, while the `configuration`  is `null` if I try to use it like `object Util { @Inject var configuration: play.api.Configuration = _  }`?

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
Play.current.configuration
```

however that will (probably) no longer be possible with Play 2.6.

Ideally, however, you would pass the configuration in as a parameter to that method of the object or, use a class instead of an object.

What I somtimes do to migrate 'from object to class':

```
class MyComponent @Inject() (config: Configuration) {
  // here goes everything nice
  def doStuff = ???
}

object MyComponent {
  @deprecated("Inject MyComponent")
  def doStuff = {
    val instance = Play.current.injector.instanceOf[MyComponent]
    instance.doStuff
  }
}
```

This way, you're not breaking existing code while all users of your methods can slowly migrate to using classes.

Comment: @deprecated now takes two arguments :)
and even if i added the version, using this won't work :)